# Python‘s print function failed in Docker

Tags: python, docker

I want to print something in my python Docker. But it failed when print function in While loop.
It works when it like this:

```
import time

time.sleep(5)
print('hello')
```

But it failed, it means, nothing will be show up in my terminal, when it like this:

```
import time

while True:
   time.sleep(5)
   print('hello')
```

And, here is my Dockerfile, the `app.py` is the code.

```
FROM python:3.5.0
CMD python app.py
```

Could somebody help me out?

Answer (score -1):

I have fixed it by another question. 
You can simply run the python like this in Dockerfile:

```
CMD python -u app.py
```